# PasswordSignInAsync doesn't work correctly (Identity)

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, controller, asp.net-identity, identity

I am testing my `Login()` method in postman, and It always return false.

There is a user in my db with email: 111@ukr.net, username: 111@ukr.net, password: 111111.

When I use `CheckPasswordAsync` for this user, I get true.

When I try to pass object user instead of username in parameter I get false too.

My post method

```
        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Login()//[FromBody]UserModel model)
        {
            var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync
                ("111@ukr.net", "111111", false, false);

            //var user = await _userManager.FindByEmailAsync("111@ukr.net"); 
            //var result1 = await _userManager.CheckPasswordAsync  
            //    (user, "111111");

            //var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync
            //     (user, "111111", false, false);
            if (result.Succeeded == true)
            {
                return Ok(result);
            }
            else
            {
                return BadRequest(result);
            }
        }
```

In postman I always get

```
{
    "succeeded": false,
    "isLockedOut": false,
    "isNotAllowed": true,
    "requiresTwoFactor": false
}
```

Code from my Startup.cs

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddControllers();
            services.AddDbContext<ApplicationContext>();
            services.AddIdentity<User, IdentityRole>(opts =>
            {
                opts.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true;
                opts.Password.RequiredLength = 6; 
                opts.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;  
                opts.Password.RequireLowercase = false;
                opts.Password.RequireUppercase = false; 
                opts.Password.RequireDigit = false; 
            })
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationContext>();
            services.AddTransient<IUnitOfWork, EFUnitOfWork>();
            services.AddTransient<ITestService, TestService>();
            services.AddTransient<IQuestionService, QuestionService>();
            services.AddTransient<IAnswerService, AnswerService>();
            services.AddTransient<IUserService, UserService>();
        }

        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }

            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
            });
        }
```

Comment: Can you please provide the configuration code? As the response says, that action is not allowed, so it should be something related to those configurations and not the Identity implementation in ASP.

Comment: @TonyTroeff I have edit my post

Comment: So, the first hing I have noticed is that part of the code where a confirmation is required for every account in order to sign in. Is this condition fulfilled?

Comment: @TonyTroeff I don’t really understand what you are talking about. What part are you talking about?

Comment: That line of code:
`opts.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true;`

Comment: @TonyTroeff Thank you a lot! It works!

Comment: You are welcome, I am happy to help you,

Comment: I also created an answer so you can mark this question as answered,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That line of code is what breaks your code:

```
opts.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true;
```

This configuration will not allow you to log in with an unconfirmed account which I think this one is.